# How to play and pause a-frame video with play-on-window-click.js example?

Tags: aframe

Dearest a-framers,

I am playing videos with a-frame and using this example:
https://github.com/chenzlabs/aframe-360-video-example/tree/main
Playing the video on click works fine, but somehow i can not manage to pause the video on another click.

I tried to change to toggle-play-on-window-click.js and in the given example it works. In my code i don't use the videosphere but the example aframe-stereo-component.js from here:
https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component
when i attach the toggle-play-on-window-click to my video component it will start playing, but not going to pause again.
also i tried to use aframe-video-controls from here:
https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-video-controls
and the status bar is working fine, but i can not click the pause button. or actually interact with the controls at all.